# How to clear selection on a virtualized ListView in UWP?

Tags: listview, win-universal-app

I am in doubt. I have a large list container possibly thousands of items. When I virtualize (which is almost a demand for performance), I get this exception as soon as I try to update the selection:

```
Failed to update selection | [Exception] System.Exception: Catastrophic failure (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED))
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.IVector`1.RemoveAt(UInt32 index)
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.VectorToListAdapter.RemoveAtHelper[T](IVector`1 _this, UInt32 index)
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.VectorToListAdapter.RemoveAt[T](Int32 index)
   at MyApp.Views.SearchView.<>c__DisplayClass9_0.<UpdateListViewSelection>b__0()
   at MyApp.Views.SearchView.<>c__DisplayClass10_0.<<ExecuteSafely>b__0>d.MoveNext()
```

I tried clearing the selection in 2 ways:

A:

```
listView.SelectedItems.Clear();
```

B:

```
for (int i = 0; i < listView.SelectedItems.Count; i++)
{
    listView.SelectedItems.RemoveAt(i--);
}
```

The alternative is not to virtualize, but that's even worse... Anyone knows how to safely clear the selection on a virtualized listview in UWP?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems important to clear the right way based on the `SelectionMode` of the ListView. Below is a safe way to clear the selection of a ListView (without having to care about the `SelectionMode` yourself):

```
public static void ClearSelection(this ListViewBase listView)
{
    Argument.IsNotNull(() => listView);

    switch (listView.SelectionMode)
    {
        case ListViewSelectionMode.None:
            break;

        case ListViewSelectionMode.Single:
            listView.SelectedItem = null;
            break;

        case ListViewSelectionMode.Multiple:
        case ListViewSelectionMode.Extended:
            listView.SelectedItems.Clear();
            break;

        default:
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
    }
}
```

Comment: This will not work if the ListView is bound to an IItemsRangeInfo. In that case, the SelectedItems is not synchronized (i.e. typically it is null). You can use this.SelectedRanges.ToList().ForEach(iir => this.DeselectRange(iir));

Also when virtualizing and using a large data set it makes sense to use ranges instead of items because it is more efficient.

Comment: By the way, the same is true for selecting items: we should either assign to SelectedItem or to add to SelectedItems depending on the SelectionMode of the control. Otherwise we're getting the same "Catastrophic failure".